# Escaping chars in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I can't find proper list (or you need to be registered to some sort of forum or not clear list) of which chars should be escaped in `.htaccess` file. I found that dots don't need to be escaped - but for me it's irracional because they have meaning in "regex".

For example this rewrite...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php\/component\/users\/\?task=registration.register [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

It has escaped all slashes which are not "beginning" but still that POST "pass through"

My question - does anyone have list which chars should be escaped?

Comment: The special meaning of a dot is "any character", which, of course, also matches a dot. So it works without escaping, but that doesn't mean you should not escape it, if you want to make sure it only matches a dot.

Answer (score 3):

> does anyone have list which chars should be escaped?

You will not find a simple list.

Whether specific chars need to be escaped in `.htaccess` (or Apache config files in general) is dependent on *context* (module/directive and argument) and what it is you want to do (use the meta-characters special meaning or match a literal character).

The only character that will universally need escaping in `.htaccess` is the *space*. Since the *space* is used as the delimiter between *arguments*. If the argument itself contains a space, then this must be escaped, otherwise the directive will simply fail to compile properly. If an argument contains a *space* then you can either backslash escape it, or surround the entire argument in double quotes. (If the argument is a regex then it may be easier/clearer to use the *whitespace* shorthand character class `\s` instead.)

> I found that dots don't need to be escaped - but for me it's irracional because they have meaning in "regex"

Well, exactly, you can't generalise and say that dots don't need to be escaped - that makes no sense. Whether a dot needs to be escaped at all depends on context and meaning. For example:

- In an ordinary string argument (such as the `RewriteCond` *TestString* or `RewriteRule` *substitution*) you do not need to escape the dot. The dot carries no special meaning here. Escaping the dot here causes no harm - it does nothing - but it can hamper readability, which is an important consideration.
- In a regex (such as the `RewriteCond` *CondPattern* or `RewriteRule` *pattern* and any other Apache directive/argument that takes a regex):

  - If you wish to match any character (except newline) then you should not escape the dot.
  - If you wish to match a literal dot, then you need to escape the dot to negate its special meaning.
  - However, to match a literal dot *inside a character class* then you do not need to escape the dot. Since when used inside a regex character class, the dot carries no special meaning.

Note that Apache uses PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) flavour of regex. The same escaping applies.

> It has escaped all slashes which are not "beginning" ...

And this doesn't really make sense. (Unfortunately there are a lot of mod_rewrite/regex examples out there that are not strictly correct.)

The slash (`/`) does not need to be escaped as it carries no special meaning in the regex (there are no *slash delimiters*). There is no harm in escaping it (except for *readability*), however, omitting the first slash and escaping the remaining looks like an error/typo. There is no reason why you would escape one and not the other.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php\/component\/users\/\?task=registration.register [NC]
> ```

However, this whole condition *looks* wrong. Not because of the backslash escapes, but because it looks like you are seemingly trying to match the query string against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable. The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the URL-path only. This will only match if the question mark (`?`) is URL-encoded as `%3F` in the request (ie. there is no query string) - which would be unusual. Ordinarily, a condition like this will never match and the request is never blocked.

Why aren't both the dots escaped? It looks like they should be in this *context*. But only you know for sure whether they should be or not.

> ```
> RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
> ```

The `L` flag is not required (it is *implied* when used with the `F` flag). The `.*` regex is not optimal, however, the `RewriteCond` directive should be removed and the URL-path should be tested in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead.

Answer (score 2):

`.htaccess` supports  much more than only `mod_rewrite`  directives.

This lists all directives Apache supports and if they are allowed in `.htaccess` files https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/quickreference.html

Not  every directive that is allowed in .htaccess has the same rules  / requirements for escaping “special” characters as many are NOT regular expressions. Typically the manual will list which rule set governs a directive

Of interest may be 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regex